# Python py2exe Not Including `os` Module

Tags: python, py2exe

I have a python program which imports `os` so that I can retrieve the application's path (i.e. `os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))`). I have been using py2exe to make this python file into an exe, and I have had no issues until I started to use `os`. Here is the command window (notice it says `1 missing Modules`):
[image]

When I try to open the `.exe` that gets created, it closes on me immediately. All the other imports seem to work fine, and they are: `win32api, win32con, time, msvcrt, win32gui, re`. Again, the `.exe` stops working properly when I import `os` but the Python project itself works fine. What can I do to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use cx-Freeze for create a .exe on windows instead of py2exe.

Comment: I'm getting the same problem. Here is a picture of the command window: http://i.imgur.com/GEUZDMR.png

Comment: With cx-Freeze yo don't need to use a setup.py, you can execute the cxfreeze script directly on you helloworld.py that you want turn to helloworld.exe.